# com.meteor.cordova-update.tgz: No such file or directory

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to build a meteor 1.1.0.3 app for mobiles on a new computer with the command:

> meteor run android

The **Installing Cordova plugins** indicator goes to 54% and then produces the error:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: project/.meteor/local/cordova-build/local-
Warning: plugins/com.meteor.cordova-update.tgz: No such file or directory
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 784)
```

How to fix meteor 1.1.0.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved by deleting .meteor/local in the project and then running:

> meteor install-sdk android
>
> meteor install-sdk ios